# Sorting paragraphs in bash (awk or sed)?

Tags: bash, awk

To sort various paragraphs (abc order) I tried:

> awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } { a[FNR]=$0 } END {
> PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc" for (i in a) print a[i] ORS } '
> myrecords.txt

But it won't sort. Sample records:

```
Ham  
this is good  
(mind the mail)

Cheese  
I'm fine

Turkey
(empty)
```

Blocks of text might got one or more lines, seperated by one or more blank lines or even a date instead of a blank. The latter can be solved by replacing the date with a blank line.

Desired result:

```
Cheese
I'm fine

Ham 
this is good 
(mind the mail)

Turkey 
(empty)
```

Comment: Works just fine over here, except: 1. Add the missing `;` in `END` before the `for`. 2. Are you sure you are using GNU awk as other awks won't sort the data out-of-the-box?

Comment: See answers to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71213089/3776858).

Comment: What version of AWK are you using? Please check that using `awk --version` and add it to your question

Comment: Assuming you've made sure you're using GNU awk, are you sure those blank lines are really empty and don't have a space or `CR` (aka `\r`, aka `^M`) in them? [edit] your question to show the output of running `cat -Ev file` on your input file.

Comment: @Daweo
GNU Awk 4.1.0
and busybox v1.22.1 based gawk as well

Comment: @EdMorton 
Sample `^M$ 
^M$ 
List of groups 
^M$ ???? Swiss ???? ^M$ ^M$ t.me/unarkt_sa^M$ ^M$ t.me/unkot^M$ ^M$ ^M$ Stutt^M$ t.me/versStutt^M$ ^M$ ^M$ TM-|bin^M$ Zu son tier: @fule^M$ ^M$ ^M$ FM-|h^M$ t.me/fuehSIC^M$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output shown in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265301/sorting-paragraphs-in-bash-awk-or-sed?noredirect=1#comment125976695_71265301) your lines all end in control-Ms (`Carriage Returns`) so the ones that look empty actually aren't so your whole file is a single record when RS is null. Run `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'` on your input file to remove those `CR`s and then run the awk command again. See the difference below before and after I run sed on the input to remove the CRs:

```
$ cat -Ev file
Ham  ^M$
this is good  ^M$
(mind the mail)^M$
^M$
Cheese  ^M$
I'm fine^M$
^M$
Turkey^M$
(empty)^M$
```

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}' file | cat -Ev
1 <Ham  ^M$
this is good  ^M$
(mind the mail)^M$
^M$
Cheese  ^M$
I'm fine^M$
^M$
Turkey^M$
(empty)^M>$
```

```
$ sed 's/\r$//' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

```
$ cat -Ev file
Ham  $
this is good  $
(mind the mail)$
$
Cheese  $
I'm fine$
$
Turkey$
(empty)$
```

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print NR, "<" $0 ">"}' file | cat -Ev
1 <Ham  $
this is good  $
(mind the mail)>$
2 <Cheese  $
I'm fine>$
3 <Turkey$
(empty)>$
```

See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information on those DOS line endings.